# Auto-censorship in questions' titles?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Today, I saw this interesting question: [How did "s***" and "the s***" come to mean opposite things?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/230399/how-did-s-and-the-s-come-to-mean-opposite-things)

See how the title is automatically censured?

But then, on Serverfault:

[image: Serverfault printscreen]

It this a bug or was it intentional?

Answer (score 4):

The question was edited to sanitise the title, as you can see in the [revisions](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/230399/revisions).

It can take some time for other references to it to catch up and display the edited title.

Comment: That should explain it... Dumb me -.- Thank you for not bashing me. If required (since you have the 'diamond' in the name), you may delete this question to do not cause confusion.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You should be able to delete your own question, as long as there are no upvoted answers. If you upvoted the answer, then... downvote it or if you can't do that, edit the answer, and then change your vote. If you can't do that... yes a mod can. But really... this isn't a bad question to help people learn (I didn't realize the solution until Andrew gave it).

Comment: @Mitch I didn't realized it either. But it wasn't me who upvoted it. I have no idea who was. But if it helped you, I will keep it here.

Comment: Matt E. Эллен Says the title edit was for "Complying with SE title rules". Can you link to that post. I assume it is MSE. I am unaware of this rule.

Comment: @fredsbend While it might be in MSE, it *is* specified in ELU. [Ref one](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/is-swearing-allowed-in-questions/6573#6573) | [Ref two](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4989/do-we-have-any-general-guidelines-on-flagging) "It’s customary to play safe with titles and sanitise any that might be Not Safe For Work."